# Rails 4 and Paperclip, Unpermitted parameter: attachment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I found some solutions but none of them worked.

`upload.rb`:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  # This method associates the attribute ":attachment" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment,
    :content_type => /\Aimage\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)\z/,
    :message => "file type is not allowed (only images)"
end
```

`issue.rb`:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :uploads
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, allow_destroy: true
end
```

partial form for Issue:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @issue], wrapper: :horizontal_form, html: { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", remote: true, id: "my-form" } do |f| %>
    <% f.input :title %>
        <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone-upload">
            <div class="fallback">
                <%= f.input :attachment, as: :file, multiple: true, name: "upload[attachment]" %>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <%= f.button :submit, id:"submit", class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

`issue_controller.rb`:

```
def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(
      :title,
      uploads_attributes: [:id, :attachment, :issue_id]
    )
end
```

**UPDATE**

OK so my console log:

```
 Started POST "/projects/1/issues" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-03 13:36:19 +0100
    Processing by IssuesController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "issue"=>{"title"=>"kljjl;kklj",  "attachment"=>"upload[attachment]"}
      Project Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    Unpermitted parameter: attachment
       (9.5ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/1
    Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

`upload_controller.rb`:

```
def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:attachment)
end
```

The idea here is : *Paperlip have object :attachment. This object is in Upload model and model have relationship with Issue Model. Issue model have form with Upload attribute.*

Update 16:45 03.03.16

I have updated form to use properly nested attributes but still have the same error

```
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone-upload">
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :uploads do |u| %>
        <%= u.input :attachment, as: :file, multiple: true %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update 16:37**

Console Log:

```
Started POST "/projects/1/issues" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-03 16:26:03 +0100
Processing by IssuesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "issue"=>{"title"=>"wfwrv"}
```

Comment: can you share your console logs listing all the parameters?

Comment: Your controller and model set up looks correct. Can you please show the entire form instead of showing the partial only.

Comment: I believe that you're using the nested form wrong. Look at the [Simple_form nested models example](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models#an-example).

Comment: vucko you are right...i have fixed that part of form but i have still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because if you look at your form, the file input is using "attachment" as it's param name: `f.input :attachment`.

In your `issue_params` method, you did not permit the param `attachment`, only the nested param upload[attachment].

When debugging this sort of issue, you need to look at what your params are. As you can see in the log, they look like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "issue"=>{"title"=>"kljjl;kklj",  "attachment"=>"upload[attachment]"}
```

So you're submitting issue[attachment]. If that's how you'd like it be in your params, then simply remove "*uploads_attributes:*" from your params method.

Should just look like:

```
def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(
      :title,
      :id, 
      :attachment, 
      :issue_id
    )
end
```

You should no longer see the warning now. Which, by the way, is just a warning.

You do not need a Upload controller if you are never routing to uploads. Instead, to access the Upload model, do that from the Issues controller like so:

1. Take the attachment from the issues params with `image = issue_params[:attachment]`.
2. `upload = Upload.new(image)`
3. `upload.save`

Please comment if you need more clarification.

**EDIT:**

After looking your model over, don't do `Upload.new`. Instead, inside your #create method, use the newly created issue to create a connected upload: `issue.uploads.new(image)`. This all depends on what your #create method looks like. I'm currently assuming you've made a new issue in it, and then saved it.

I would also suggest getting rid of the upload model. Paperclip is a great gem that takes all the hassle out of uploading. Why create an upload model, when Paperclip will seamlessly add the attachment to your issue model?

**Edit 2:**

To make a nested form, you write it like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploads do |upload| %>
  <%= upload.input :attachment %>
<% end %>
```

And use that in place of the single input you currently have. Does that make sense? You are literally nesting a form inside a form.

Comment: so...Upload model is to handle uploads thats why i seperate this 2 models. In Issue form im using upload attributte (:attachment) and dropzone take this element and using url (required if drozpone is creating pragmatically) on POST action so i just redirect dropzone to upload controller to create attachment there. Thats why i need nested form attributes

Comment: But you didn't add "dropzone" to your form. Just to the file input? And your form is never hitting the uploads controller, at least not currently, and I don't see how it possibly would based on what I'm looking at. If there is more relevant code, than please share it. My answer is based on the code you originally posted.

Comment: @Skrypter So I think I understand what you're trying to do now. If you want to nest an upload form *inside* the issue form, you need to actually nest it, not just put f.input. So, see my edit.

Comment: my dropzone is created pragmatically it means on element...when i hit "Created Issue" first i have upload from upload controller to send images to s3 using paperclip and after upload the form is creating...

Comment: @Skrypter So is that working? When you submit this form, your upload controller is being hit? I ask only because your console log shows nothing but your issues controller being hit. The params warning is because of what I explained in my answer. If uploads are working I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: OK its working now! i just have problem with properly use nested forms...but the problem is now: Why attachment isnt on my params after submit the form ( i have no idea how to glue issue_id to upload attachment in this case) - (I have updated my main post)

Comment: @Skrypter this is why I suggested having a separate upload model didn't make sense to me. Could you explain why you don't want to upload the image from the Issues model, and have paperclip add an attachment column to 'Issues' for you? That's generally how paperclip is used. There is no need to make a whole new model, just put all those validations inside the issue model. 

You cannot bind the issue_id in the form, because it does not exist yet. It only exists after the issue is created by the issue controller, so only after this form is submitted.

Comment: The separete model is for 2 reasons: 
1) Single Responsibility
2) Upload Model handle uploads and issue isnt good idea to put there that functionality

Comment: @Skrypter But the upload model doesn't handle anything. You are using the paperclip gem. The paperclip gem handles everything. If you read the paperclip docs, you will see they do not have an upload model. That isn't how it's used. If anything has an attached file, then you use paperclip to add that column to the relevant model. As I've explained, you are trying to link an upload to an issue that does not exist yet in your database. That isn't possible. Using Issue.last is not a safe method of getting the correct issue.

Comment: @Skrypter Always important to read the docs, and see how the creators expect their code to be used: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: you were right...i dont need seperate model to handle upload using only paperclip. And if someone have any question because have similar problem comment just "add comment"

Comment: @Skrypter glad to hear things are working. I should have been clearer when I first answered your question, that was my bad. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone-upload">
<div class="fallback">
  <%= f.fields_for Upload.new do |u| %>
    <%= u.input :attachment, as: :file, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```